# Solution to non-homogeneous partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following second-order non-homogeneous partial differential equation:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} (\sigma^x)^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_+ (x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} + \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) \frac{\partial V_+ (x_t)}{\partial x_t} - e_+ V_+ (x_t) &= -\frac{- 2x_t + 2 \lambda e_- (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+} 
\end{align}

To solve it, first I find the general solution of the homogeneous equation:

\begin{align}
V_+^g(x_t) = c_+^1 H_{-\frac{e_+}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x }\right) + c_+^2 \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_+}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t -a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2}\right)
\end{align}

I know that the degree of the hermite polynomial $-\frac{e_+}{a_1}$ is not an integer. I have been advised that dropping the hermite component should still yield a valid solution. Therefore, I now want to find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. Then, the general solution to the nonhomogeneous equation is equal to the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and the particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

Normally, I would use the variation of parameters method but if I set $c_1=0$, the Wronskian is zero, so I cannot use it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first simplify the notation: the differential equation can be rewritten as
$$
aV''(x)+(b+cx)V'(x)+dV(x)=ex+f, \tag{1}
$$
where $a,b,\dots,f$ are constants. Now, as suggested in my comment, let's try a particular solution to $(1)$ of the form $V_p(x)=Ax+B$:
$$
(b+cx)A+d(Ax+B)=ex+f\Rightarrow (c+d)Ax+(bA+dB)=ex+f. \tag{2}
$$
If $c+d\neq 0$ and $d\neq 0$ (which seems to be the case), the solution to $(2)$ is
\begin{align}
A&=\frac{e}{c+d}, \\
B&=\frac{1}{d}(f-bA)=\frac{1}{d}\left(f-\frac{be}{c+d} \right). \tag{3}
\end{align}
Therefore, $V_p(x)=Ax+B$, with $A$ and $B$ given by $(3)$, is indeed a particular solution to $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer